# Connecting between Laravel 5.3 and Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I have set up L5 and angular2 inside it : Among Laravel regular directories (app , bootstrap , cgi-bin, config ...) there are angular following directories : node_modules, angular2 , css, es6-promise, es6-shim etc.

Angular hello world and other simple app works fine : welcome.blade.view consists  label.The file app.component.js sends data to it as I expect. I see nice result when I route (localhost:8000 or localhost:8000/area_owners) , this is angular 2 result. Problem is , now I want to send data to these views from the proper PHP controller for example from area_owners.php controller. how do I do that ? how do I send $area_owners (this var stores array or object in PHP language) from area_owners.php controller, which is located in app->Http->Controllers->area_owners.php, to public->typscript->app.component.ts (this file controlls the view area_owners.php , which is located in resources->view->area_owner.php

Comment: Use angular http to call ur laravel route as an API and have it return data (as Json probably) to your view

Comment: Hi Tam thank you for your answer. Do you have any code example of this api or reference link to it ?

Comment: Just have a google for "angular2 and laravel" there are tons of tutorials and examples I can't recommend a specific one just see which most closely resembles what u are trying to do and is easy to follow

Comment: Oh and if you are having angular be sort of part of your laravel app (or even if not) you should have a look at the laracast about laravel passport and just switch out vue for angular

Comment: Hi Tam . I tried using Http class im typescript in order to parse json file by using httpUrl like that: "private area_ownersUrl = '/api/v1/area_owners'; "      Problem is: the import of Class Http and the import of class Response didnt Succeed . Http class in not located in angular2/http dir. Angular.Io sais it is suppose to be in @angular/http. What is @angular dir ? there isnt any dir like that but instead there is Angular2 dir. Who knows why ????